# programmatically create input file in smt-lib2 format

Tags: c, z3, smt

I am using C language to check the satisfiability of a formula using Z3 API. At present, I am converting a formula into SMT-LIB2 format manually.

Is there any way to do it automatically in C?

I am thinking of writing my own function to convert a formula (infix notation) into SMT-LIB2 format.

Comment: Assuming that your source format is essentially arbitrary, how would any programming language allow you to magically convert data from one format to another? Automating the process, on the other hand, is easy: you "just" need to write functions that do the conversion. Other options: use an existing parser, e.g. https://es-static.fbk.eu/people/griggio/misc/smtlib2parser.html, or drop your own data format and use Z3 via its API.

Comment: You would probably need to use the function `Z3_benchmark_to_smtlib_string`